# Opposite of "sexy clothes"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, vocabulary

What would be the opposite of "sexy clothes", as in "clothes that hide sexual bits" ? Like for a woman, a top that would hide and make her breasts much less pronounced?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask any father with a teenage daughter.

Comment: *As* a father with a teenage girl, the opposite of "sexy clothes" is "anything I'll actually let my daughter wear" :-)

Comment: As a father of three young women (16, 19, 21) I can assure you that there are plenty of clothes at Walmart I wouldn't approve of, were my approval requested. As it has not been, however, I suppose the point is moot.

Comment: "[Unsexy clothes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unsexy+clothes%22&client=firefox-b&oq=%22unsexy+clothes%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3...5917.7701.0.8149.2.2.0.0.0.0.201.318.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..2.0.0._2Q_dG-KQBc)" is an actual term found used commonly enough online.

Comment: @Fattie Pretty sure people's vocabularies are richer on this end. There's also several thousand 'single-word-request' and 'word-choice' questions that suggest it's ok.

Comment: [That old, baggy t-shirt from that team building exercise you did for your old work](https://youtu.be/WGOohBytKTU).

Comment: http://www.poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/fashionable/

Comment: @lly there comes a point when the suggestions are no longer connected to the question but are synonyms of answers already given. "Too broad" (too many *good* answers) as this one, is a valid reason for putting on hold this question.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/modest)

> ### Modest
>
> 3. (of a woman) dressing or behaving so as to avoid impropriety or indecency, especially to avoid attracting sexual attention.
>
>    ‘the modest women wear long-sleeved dresses and all but cover their faces’

I think *modest clothing* conveys the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but surely ‘modest’ is the opposite of ‘immodest’ or ‘shameless’. Clothing can be ‘sexy’ without being either of these.

Comment: @Tuffy By itself certainly *immodest* and *shameless* are better antonyms for *modest* than *sexy*. If the question was "what's the opposite of modest", *sexy* would be an odd answer.  But in this context, I can't think of a better phrase for "clothes that hide sexual bits" than "modest clothes". Avoiding attracting sexual attention is right in the dictionary definition. Can you?

Comment: But must every adjective have a corresponding antonym?  There is no reason why it should be so. Moreover, it is quite possible to imagine clothing that is modest but also sexy, partly because ‘sexiness’ is subjective.  A person that fantasises about nuns would presumably find a nun’s very modest habit sexy.   There is in any case  fallacy about in saying that to be sexy clothing must reveal or highlight the ‘sexual bits’.

Comment: @Tuffy Actually, no, it can't. "Sexy" clothing is clothing that is *designed* to inspire sexual attraction, typically by putting emphasis on the person's body shape or exposing skin. While weird fetishes exist, a nun's outfit is most certainly *designed* to discourage this outcome as much as possible by de-emphasizing body shape and covering skin.

Comment: The question actually is a bit contradictory. Opposite of sexy could be something like "frumpy" [you could have something frumpy that's still revealing though IMO, unlikely, but possible]. But "clothes that hide sexual bits" could be something like "modest", "conservative" (or even just "not slutty" or "normal") depending on the prevailing mores of the community.

Comment: @pbhj Exactly.  Not every adjective has to have an opposite.  If there were one it would probably be the perhaps rather disappointing “unsexy”:  a bit of a “turn-off”.

Comment: @Tuffy, I don't think "unsexy" is an antonym, it's closer to being agnostic as to the sexiness of the outfit, rather than it being opposite-to-sexy. Context and intent need clarifying to get close to a good answer.

Comment: @Tuffy you're quite right about *sexy* being subjective. The OP, however, was very specific about what s/he was looking for: a word for "clothes that hide sexual bits". In this case, it doesn't matter if the nun's habit aroused someone. The "sexual bits" were minimized as much as possible.

Comment: @Tuffy - You seem to be caught up in the title of the question, as opposed to the full question. I think Dan has nailed it twice; once when he answered with _modest_, and once again when he replied to your initial comment.

Comment: I agree with @Tuffy and suggest that the opposite of "sexy" is definitely "frumpy". I could describe clothes as *modest but still a bit sexy* or even *modestly sexy*. I don't see "modest" clothes as "hiding" obvious secondary sex characteristics. "Frumpy" clothes are very loose and completely hide any information about the shape of the body underneath.

Answer (score 49):

**Frumpy**

[Defined by Merriam-Webster as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frumpy)

> dowdy, drab

[and perhaps more relevantly by the Urban Dictionary as:](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=frumpy)

> A female with lack of concern for appearance. Often characterized by sweatpants, frizzy hair, gramma panties and a paisty complexion.

Comment: This is an adjective that's usually used to describe a person rather than a style of clothing.

Comment: @Cubic - I've seen it used to describe articles of clothing and entire outfits as well.

Comment: Although I am _shocked_ that Urban Dictionary would show any misogyny, this word can apply to men (and their clothes) as well.

Comment: @thumbtackthief the misogyny is, unfortunately, in the culture and usage. Even the OED says frumpy is [(of a woman or her clothes)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/frumpy).

Comment: @DanHall I understand--I wasn't blaming the person who wrote the answer.  I feel like the word can be used for men as well, though--I'd certainly understand it to mean the same thing if I heard it.

Comment: @thumbtackthief I have never heard of ‘frumpy’ used of a male.  It is an insult used of females.  That by itself rules out ‘frumpy’ as an opposite of ‘sexy’.

Comment: @Tuffy And are you suggesting your experience with the English language comprises the entirety of humanity's?  Because I have definitely told my husband he looked frumpy when he wasn't put together, and he seemed to understand what I meant just fine.

Comment: @Tuffy - President Obama used it to refer to himself, [almost ten years ago](http://politicalticker.blogs.cnn.com/2009/07/21/im-a-little-frumpy-obama-says/). That by itself rules out 'frumpy' as a word used exclusively of females. It's also been used to describe male [golfers](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/2009-05-07/sports/orl_1_paul-goydos-alma-mater-golf-channel), [artists](https://artappreciation101.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/diego-rivera-and-frida-kahlo-the-odd-couple/), and [dance moves](http://observer.com/2008/03/adam-green-scrapes-off-the-mold/).

Comment: The fact that "frumpy-looking" can be used for males is like pointing out that "pregnant-looking" could be used for males or "handsome" could be used for females.   And Cubic, it's totally commonplace to use it as an adjective for clothes (exactly as with "sexy" "stylish" "boring" etc.)

Comment: Note that this answer is utterly, totally, completely incorrect.  Indeed frumpy clothes **are often very sexual** - wearing pyjamas and smelly undies out.  Frumpy is the opposite of neat, formal.  (And note that neat, formal clothes can be either incredibly sexual/revealing, or, very cover up, unsexual.)  "Frumpy" is totally wrong for the question at hand.

Comment: @Fattie Nope, *casual* is the opposite of formal. Frumpy requires (as per the dictionary definition) a disregard for your clothes being attractive. It's perfectly possible to have clothes which are clean and neat, but which are frumpy due to poor fit, a design which is inherently unattractive, or simply bad taste in fabric patterns. Pyjamas may qualify as frumpy if they are saggy, shapeless and unattractive, but that has nothing to do with wearing them outdoors.

Comment: @graham Nope, (you can look in the OED for a definition {no connection to what you stated})  Your extended discussion on the sense is perfectly fine, as is mine.  The relevant point is it is indeed fairly common for frumpy to be sexual. A bit of a hot mess.  Sure, frumpy usually means just "old-fashioned, dowdy" (ie as in the OED).  The point is that frumpy simply has no connection at all to what the OP is asking, which is simply modest, demure, conservative, baggy, concealing, etc.

Comment: @Fattie Collins has precisely one definition - "dowdy, drab, or unattractive" to quote their exact words. As I said, this is a quality of the clothes the person is wearing, in that they are inherently not attractive or ill-fitting. It doesn't relate to whether they are neat or formal, so this doesn't cover your use of it. If it's common round your way to use *frumpy* to mean that, it's usage which isn't in my dictionary at least. Does the OED give a different definition?

Comment: `paisty`? I'd think `pasty`; is this some alternative spelling?

Answer (score 24):

[Demure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demure) defined by the OED as

> (of a woman or her behaviour) reserved, modest, and shy.
>
> (of clothing) lending a modest appearance.

is a suitable antonym for "sexy".

Interestingly, however, the [Collins online dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demure) includes the suggestion that *demure* clothing and actions can be adopted to increase attractiveness in this entry:

> If you describe someone, usually a young woman, as demure, you mean they are quiet and rather shy, usually in a way that you like and find appealing,
>
> She's very demure and sweet.
> The luscious Miss Wharton gave me a demure but knowing smile.

Comment: I don't think Collins disagrees with you in that quote - the "demure" part is certainly not sexual (the "but" connecting to "knowing" is intended as contrast there).

Comment: I don't think demure is the opposite of sexy. This makes me think of the script from Total Recall -- computer: How do you like your women? ... Douglas Quaid: sleazy, demure.

Comment: "demure" is exactly correct.  it's a way of describing clothes precisely as the OP described clothes.  (Basically, deemphasizing sexuality.)  A perfect answer.

Comment: @octopus I don't remember that line from Total Recall but I would suggest that Quaid is either suggesting that any sort of woman would attract him (the equivalent of giving an answer like tall, short: slim, voluptuous: blonde, brunette) or he was deliberately giving an illogical answer in an attempt to confuse the computer.

Answer (score 22):

> [**Wholesome**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wholesome)   2. Conducive to or promoting social or moral well-being, especially in reflecting conventional moral values: wholesome entertainment; a politician with a wholesome public image.

and/or

> **[Conservative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conservative)**
>   ​ 
>   If you are conservative in your appearance, you usually do not like fashionable or modern clothes or hairstyles: 
>   He's a very conservative dresser - he always looks like he's wearing his father's clothes!

Comment: Wholesome isn't very idiomatic when referring to clothing (at least not in American English). Conservative certainly is, though.

Comment: The classic "little black dress" is undeniably a conservative clothing choice under many circumstances, but it is sexy without being overly revealing.

Comment: While a person dressed in conservative modest clothing may be said to have a wholesome appearance, the clothing is only one part of the overall image.  Hair, demeanor, jewelry, makeup on women, all help build a wholesome appearance.

Comment: @arp I have only ever heard 'little black dress' used to refer to when someone wants to look very sexy. While not necessarily revealing, I've certainly never heard it used for someone trying to *cover up* or dress modestly/conservatively. The "little" in "little black dress" directly counters such a notion.

Comment: @TylerH Arp's point wasn't that LBDs aren't sexy; it's that they are a conservative (long established, not daring/bold) fashion choice on occasions when something flashy or glamorous could be worn instead. In other words, 'conservative' can be used precisely to describe sexy fashions and is questionable as an answer.

Comment: I've seen "wholesome" be used to describe revealing women

Comment: @lly Hmm, well I disagree that established or even common means 'conservative'.

Answer (score 7):

To add another possibility although not precisely an answer(because it is more absence of sexual accentuation than opposite of):

If one was looking for a relatively positive word that meant "**not-overtly-sexy-without-suggesting-innocence-or-drabness**" you might try:

> [**discreet** at Oxford Online Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discreet)
>
> 1 Careful and prudent in one's speech or actions, especially in order to keep something confidential or to avoid embarrassment.
>
> ‘we made some discreet inquiries’
>
> 1.1 Intentionally unobtrusive.
>
> ‘a discreet cough’
>
> [**discreetly** at Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discreetly)
>
> 1 In a careful and prudent manner, especially in order to keep something confidential or to avoid embarrassment.
>
> *‘he discreetly inquired whether the position was still available’*
>
> 1.1 In an intentionally unobtrusive manner.
>
> *‘she coughed discreetly’*

Discreet might also mean not flashy or not attention-grabbing as much as not sexy ( perhaps a weakness to this suggestion if you ONLY wanted not-sexy).

"Discreet" is still a bit of a euphemism(whether we want it to be or not there are biases) suggesting "less sexy" to those preoccupied with such, yet it spares the connotations of "innocent" as well as sparing criticism of "unfashionable" or "plain" (in plain's worse senses ... absence of flashiness could still be 'understated' while still high quality)

Of course there might be other words that just sidestep other ways "pleasant", "professional", "athletic", "sharp" etc yet none of those directly mean "absence of", or "done to avoid".  **discreet** will suggest:

- "not purposefully sexy (as well as not flashy and not attention grabbing) Without suggesting 'innocence' and generally not 'plain' or 'old fashioned' .  More 'tasteful' than merely conservative.
- "discreet" can be more gender neutral - so suggest fewer 'woman should be' stereotypes. (generally men's suits are discreet, but Elvis dressing discreetly would lose his white suit and/or Al Capone would lose his accentuated pin-stripes).
- "discreet" can go well alongside positive adjectives.  i.e. "Meryl Streep showed up in a discreet yet fashionable pantsuit for her intellectual property trial"

Comment: Apparently, I can't fix typos?

Comment: @swbarnes2 you're welcome to. I'll try to go through and fix them myself later if you can't  (and thank you in advance if you can)

Comment: I tried, it wouldn't let me make a change of < 6 characters.

Answer (score 6):

'[Modest](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/451018/171986)', '**sensible**', (kinda dated) '[demure](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/451044/171986)', and (in some circles) '[conservative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/451020/171986)' are the nice ways to say this. '[Frumpy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/451057/171986)', '**dowdy**', '**shapeless**', and (in other circles) 'conservative' are disparaging terms. All are mostly focused on *women's* sartorial choices.

Two unisex terms that come to mind are

> ## [Unisex](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/214732)
>
> > **A.** *adj.* ... **3.** Designed to be suitable for either sex; not peculiar to one sex. ...

People *can* be sexy in unisex clothing (wifebeaters) but it's usually rather difficult (Mao suits) and certainly not what they're designed for.

> ## [Baggy](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14642)
>
> > **A.** *adj.*  **1.** Puffed or bulging out, hanging in loose folds. ...

Again, not necessarily *un*sexy, but the labels you'd see or search for when looking for clothes that are intended to be worn for utility or comfort rather than accentuating sexual attractiveness.

---

The best word for *exactly* what your example described, though, is

> ## [Concealing](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38066#eid8628116)
>
> > **1.** [*adj.*] **a.** ... keep[ing] from the knowledge of others ...
> >
> > **2.** [*adj.*] **a.** ... put[ting] or keep[ing] out of sight or notice... prevent[ing] from being visible. ...

The other terms all describe the *character* of the person (usu. woman) as revealed by their clothing choices or the *style* of the clothes themselves. 'Concealing' is the adjective describing the *action* of covering and hiding away all those fun bits from the eyes of those who shouldn't be noticing them.

Comment: Modest clothes/clothing... *check*. Conservative dress code and dress conservatively... *check*. Frumpy clothes... *check*. Concealing clothes...? not a common collocation, and more often than not, concealing is associated with hiding a belly or a gun.

Comment: I'd go for "shapeless", something that is shapeless is large, baggy, and more often than not, unsexy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're not wrong. It's not 'concealing clothing'. (Gun-ready clothes are apparently often 'concealed[-carry] clothing'.) We *don't* usually focus on the action itself; we usually focus on the virtue or lack thereof and secondarily focus on the cut of the clothes (as with your 'shapeless'). On the other hand, Joan of Arc and Mulan concealed their breasts. A Muslim might say burqas are 'modest'; an impolitic fashionista might call them 'frumpy', 'boring', or 'repressive'; but there is no question that it is *concealing*.

Comment: I'll go ahead and add 'shapeless' to the list though, since it's apparently unmentioned in the other answers.

Comment: "sensible" to me refers to functionality, not appearance. If you're going horseback riding, shorts would be sensible, an evening gown would not.

Comment: @Acccumulation A person could call a slinky sequined dress 'sensible' when visiting a club, but that's not actually the connotation of the word. 'Sensible' refers to functionality *other than* sexiness.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways to go with this:

The excellent answer already given of **modest**, which very neatly encapsulates the request for covering and hiding body parts, though several people have pointed out that clothing does not necessarily need to be revealing to be sexy.

The "sorting the underwear drawer" answer of **utilitarian** which stresses the choice of form versus function.

> utilitarian:
>   designed to be useful or practical rather than attractive.
>   synonyms:practical, functional, pragmatic, serviceable, useful, sensible, efficient, utility, workaday, no-frills;

Some but not all of the listed synonyms would work as well:. **practical**, **functional**, and sometimes **sensible** (most often seen in this context as "sensible shoes".)

This is not the whole story, of course. The nicer shirts that I wear to the office are neither plain/functional/utilitarian, nor sexy/immodest, they are just pretty shirts, a touch on the feminine side (and thus unlikely to be practical or durable), but not drifting over the line into "sexy".

(I know all the OP wanted was a word but there is a lot of cultural connotation and baggage around this area of language and social conduct.)

Comment: A t-shirt is "utilitarian", sensible, practical, and very functional but it can also show off a woman's bosom handsomely.

Answer (score 3):

***appropriate*** or ***appropriately***

[adjective]
suitable or fitting for a particular purpose, person, occasion, etc.
an appropriate example; an appropriate dress.

source: [Dictonary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/appropriate?s=t)

Comment: An "appropiate" dress is not necessarily not-sexy. E.g. bikinis are "appropiated" if you are at the beach.

Comment: @SJuan76: Bikinis are only _appropriated_ if someone's running around stealing them, or if someone has to use their bikini as an improvised wound dressing.  Bikinis are, however, _appropriate_ at the beach.  :-P

Comment: a bikini is "appropriate" at the beach, as a welding mask is appropriate when welding.  But the adjective "appropriate" relating to clothing has a clear meaning of, basically, formal, demure - and indeed is exactly what the OP is asking for, in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other good answers (both "modest" and "demure" came to my mind), you may depending on context wish to consider

- [**professional**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/professional): exhibiting a courteous, conscientious, and generally businesslike manner in the workplace
- [**no-nonsense**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-nonsense): only interested in doing what is necessary or achieving what is intended
- [**staid**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/staid): gives an impression of age, of being old-fashioned
- [**prim**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prim): easily shocked by sexual overtones

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **[austere](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/austere)** : *severely simple; without ornament*

Answer (score 1):

[Dowdy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dowdy) might also be appropriate in some contexts.

> Oxford English Dictionary: (of a person or their clothes) unfashionable and unstylish in appearance (typically used of a woman)
>
> ‘she could achieve the kind of casual chic which made every other woman around her look dowdy’

Answer (score 0):

## Unflattering, Unattractive or Unappealing

You might try one of these:

> (Un)[flattering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flattering) : (2) : (not) helping to enhance attractiveness
> (Un)[attractive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attractive) : (1)a : (not) arousing interest or pleasure
> (Un)[appealing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appealing) : (1) : (not) having appeal

Answer (score -1):

maybe sensuous or proper clothing

Comment: "sensuous" is a synonym for "sexy" ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sensuous ). Did you perhaps mean "sensible"?

Comment: yes, you are right